# Rich Notification With Firebase (FCM)

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending web push notification message with C# Mvc Project which is developed for FCM but i want to send messages with images.
Is there a way to send Rich Notification with FCM. 
And also we have 3.400 clients for notifications , sometimes , some of the clients don't get the notification. How can we fix the this problem.
Thank You..

```
self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (subscription)
     {
         var endP = subscription.endpoint;
         return fetch('url' + endP,
             {
                 method: 'get',
                 headers: {
                     "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
                 }
             }).then(function (res)
             {
                 return res.json().then(function (data)
                 {
                     var notification = data;
                     if (notification == null)
                         return;
                     var title = notification.Title;
                     var message = notification.Message;
                     var iconUrl = notification.Icon;
                     var tag = notification.Tag;
                     var url = notification.Url;
                     return self.registration.showNotification(title,
                         {
                             body: message,
                             icon: iconUrl,
                             tag: tag,
                             data:
                                 {
                                     url: url,

                                 }
                         });
                 });
             })
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, sending images through push notifications is not advisable and at the same time not that usually possible due to the [payload size limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

However, You could make use of a `data` message payload and provide the URL of the image you'd like to use (similar to the way the [`icon`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) parameter works) and process the image from the URL.